# Inline functions (.NET x64)

Tags: .net, 64-bit, inline

I am moving x86 application to x64 and discovered that no functions are inlined by compiler. Even small (<32 bytes IL and even empty). Even with compiler option `MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining`.

While in x86 all small function (and also simple big with compiler option) are inlined without problems.

Is there any way in x64 to tell compiler to inline them?

For example, the following code with "Target Platform" = x86 just loops, and with x64 - also calls EmptyFunction() 100 million times:

```
void LoopFunction()
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
    { EmptyFunction(); }
    watch.Stop();
    MessageBox.Show(watch.Elapsed.ToString());
}
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
void EmptyFunction() { }
```

Comment: How are you testing this? Note that some optimizations are disabled while running in the IDE.

Comment: I tested this: from VisualStudio with different release/debug options and also by running the result .EXE. In VisualStudio it just slower, but the result is the same - with x64 that code more than 10 times slower than with x86.

Comment: There must be something else going on in your case. Your example inlines for me. What I did: Pasted your code into a .NET 4.5 console app, fixed up the using list, changed methods to static, added a Console.ReadLine(), ran the release exe, attached a debugger, set a breakpoint after the ReadLine, pressed <CR> in the console, stepped into the function in VS. There are no calls in the for loop for me.

Comment: Realy, making that function static solves problem - function is not called. But this is not the solution, because non-static functions are still called. But thank you anyway - if there would no other ways i'll make most functions static.

Comment: Stop! This looks like a premature optimisation. Don't do it!

Answer (score 2):

That for() loop compiled to 64-bit mode by the .NET 3.5 jitter

```
0000002e  xor         r11d,r11d 
00000031  add         r11d,4 
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { EmptyFunction(); }
00000035  cmp         r11d,5F5E100h 
0000003c  jl          0000000000000031
```

By the .NET 4.5 jitter:

```
0000003a  xor         eax,eax 
0000003c  nop         dword ptr [rax] 
00000040  add         eax,4 
            for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { EmptyFunction(); }
00000043  cmp         eax,5F5E100h 
00000048  jl          0000000000000040
```

No call, just the loop survived, as it should.  The weirdo NOP instruction is there to align the branch target.

Be sure to use the Release build and be careful using a debugger because it will disable the optimizer.  Fix that with Tools + Options, Debugging, General, untick the "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" option.

Comment: Hans Passant, I think You didn't understand me (or I didn’t understand you). I wrote about function inlining – when compiler replaces function call with its code. In my example compiler should just delete EmptyFunction() call from for() loop, because it’s empty.
So, with the example (in Release mode, of course):
  1) with x86 target platform option (or with static function & x64): compiler deletes EmptyFunction() call, and function LoopFunction() run time is 0.02second – time just for empty for loop [0..100000000].

Comment: 2) with non-static function & x64: its run time is 0.26second – on every loop function EmptyFunction() is called, so it’s call didn’t deleted by compiler, while this is should be done with 'AggressiveInlining' option.
Debug/Release, "Suppress JIT..." and everything else that I could think of didn’t helped – with x64 non-static functions are not inlined.

Comment: Hmya, timing the absence of code is notoriously difficult.  You are really timing the for() loop and very small changes, like that extra NOP, have big effects.  Use hard evidence only, the actual code is the proof.

Comment: I just gave a maximum small example, which runtime would be small. Change loop count and you’ll see that its runtime changes proportionally. 0.95seconds with x86 or static and 11.5seconds with x64 for loop size = 2^32. Non extra instruction will not take 10seconds! 
After I saw, that my code from x86 runs much slower with x64, I began to search the reason. Today I calculated the time of sum and comparison of ints and the time of function calling, so now I can say, that x86 time is definitely the time of just for_loop, and x64 time is the time of for_loop + Func_Call_Time * iteration_Count.

Comment: I understand, that function call time seems little, but just that increased more than twice time of image processing, when I need to call the same small functions for each pixel and each channel. So now the time of just calling functions is bigger than calculations. By now, the only solution for x64 is to make all functions static, but this is very... uncomfortable... And to the above post: delete EmptyFunction() call from the loop with x64 and you will get x86 time, so function is definitely called.

Answer (score 1):

In my computer (.Net 4.5 x64)

If I use `AggressiveInlining`, x86 (target all cpu 32 bit preferred) takes 36 ms, x64 (target all cpu uncheck 32 bit preferred) takes 8 ms.

If I use `NoInlining`, x86 takes 240 ms, x64 takes 270 ms.

So, it definitely inlines